# Caching large file with memcached

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I have a problem I am trying to cache an array php with many data with memcached , when I try to store the array memcached return a code which is 37 so I found on google that 37 code is 37 = MEMCACHED_E2BIG
So I store my array in txt files and the weight is 5 - 6 Mb
In my memcached configuration I put 1024MB as limit so I don't understand what is wrong ...

```
/usr/bin/memcached -m 1024 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1 -c 1024
```

And my test code

```
echo '------------ SET IN MEMCACHED ---------------';

$memcached->set('post_year' , $toto);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($memcached->getResultCode()); //Return 37
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: maximum object size is 1Mb by default.  add `-I 128M` to the memcached options to verify

Comment: Even with -I 128M  I have the same return code